# python project-specific modules installation approach

Tags: python, module

I'm experienced in PHP and recently started studying Python, and right now I'm on creating a small web project using django. And I have a conceptual question about approach to installing modules in Python and django.

Example: based on expected needs for my project I've googled and downloaded django_openid module. And obviously I want to install it to my project. 
However, when I do it the prescribed way (python setup.py install) it installs it to python dir as a python module. Thus this module becomes not project specific, but system-wide.

So, what is generally right approach to install project-specific modules in python? 
Based on my PHP experience it looks strange to install high level functional modules into the python itself. I'd rather expect it to be installed in the project library and included in the project on runtime.

Or do I loose something important here?

I've googled around, but as long as this is rather a conceptual approach question - keywords search doesnt work good in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The right approach is to use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html), which allows you to install modules in an isolated environment for each project.

Answer (score 0):

Technically for any Python module to be "installed" you just have to add it to the `sys.path` variable, so that Python can find and import it.

Same goes with django apps, which are Python modules. As long as Python can find and import the django application, you just have to add it to INSTALLED_APPS in settings (and maybe few more steps usually described in the application, e.g. adding urls etc).

Comment: so basically all things I'll ever install in my setup through sys.path configuration will be visible to every possible python application I'll ever run on my machine?

Comment: Hmm, then seems like virtualenv advised in another answer is the right approach in this case. It seems not right to have every single library as a system wide module.

Comment: Indeed, I also use virtualenv for all my projects. But one day you may end up in a situation, when no virtualenv or system-wide installation permissions are available and you still want to use 3d party Python packages. That's when appending the module's path to `sys.path` will save the day.